# Using the Firebase User Management/Authentication but via PHP

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I would like to use Firebases in built user management / authentication but via PHP. I don't mind doing the actual login via JS and then passing PHP the token some how, but how would this work? Or is it even possible?

If it is, then how would you then re-validate the access/token is still valid or 'logged in' on each page via PHP? I know theres the Firebase Token PHP on Git. Just looking for an example. I know you can make your own user management with PHP, but I would like to use Firebases built in user management.

Examples would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Why downvote without explanation? This is a legitimate and practical question. One should explain if question is inappropriate.

Comment: After playing with the newest release of Firebase (2016/June) I've concluded that the easiest way to use PHP while working with Firebase would be to use JS library for the authentication and pass the token to the PHP via cookies. Then the PHP takes over and using REST does the rest.

Does that sound like what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Okay, so you would do the auth via JS as normal. Then you could send the token server side and maybe store in a session or something. Thanks. Thats kind of what I was thinking, just need to dig a bit deeper.